# Flutter - SingleChildScrollView placed at the top of the screen when keyboard pops up

Tags: input, scroll, flutter, textfield, flutter-layout

I want to make a simple screen that shows multiple TextFields in a Column, some content above and a button below. On my first attempt, without the SingleChildScrollView, I got an "renderflex overflowed" error which could be solved by placing the TextField within the SingeChildScrollView. 
Now I have the problem that the SingleChildScrollView is placed way too high on my screen when I select any TextField and the keyboard pops up. I want it to stay basically just where it is since there is enough (yellow) room for the keyboard below the SingleChildScrollView.
[This Gif shows how my app behaves.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/572w5.gif)

[This Gif shows the behavior that I would expect.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JPMS.gif)
I tried applying code from the [FlatApp-Flutter example](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/FlatApp-Flutter) to my app but was unable to find the part that actually fixes my issue.
Does anyone know how I can control how much the keyboard pushes the SingleChildScrollView up or how I can fix the issue? Thanks a lot.

```
Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
    body: new SingleChildScrollView(
        controller: _scrollController,
        child: new Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
          color: Colors.orange,
          child: new Column(children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 20.0),
              height: 200.0,
              width: 200.0,
              color: Colors.grey,
              child: new Center(
                child: Text("Show some stuff"),
              ),
            ),
            new Container(
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: new Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Label 1"),
                  ),
                  new TextField(
                    decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Label 2"),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            new RaisedButton(
              child: const Text('Start'),
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              elevation: 4.0,
              splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
              onPressed: () {
                // Perform some action
                //button1(context);
              },
            ),
          ]),
        )));
```

}

Comment: I am not able to reproduce this. Can you try using listView and see whether you are getting smoother scroll ?

Comment: And I assume you are not doing anything with `_scrollController`

Comment: Do you nest Scaffolds?

Comment: I was indeed nesting Scaffold, Günter Zöchbauer. Removing one Scaffold fixed it for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it. When implementing my navigation, I unintentionally placed my Scaffold inside the body of another Scaffold, so my structure was like this:

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My App'),
      ),
      body: ScaffoldShownInMyQuestion(),
    )
```

Returning just the SingleChildScrollView without the second Scaffold wrapping around it and using that as body fixed my problem.

Comment: Hi just wanted to drop a huge thanks for your solution.